# We say: Domain limit or Domains limit

Tags: grammar

Sorry for asking such a question... When a limit represent max number of an object, for instance, max number of domains, subdomains...

We say:

- Domain limit
- Subdomain limit

or

- Domains limit
- Subdomains limit

Comment: If I understand the scenario, you would say *the limit on the number of domains* (plural). Syntactically, *domains limit* would be the shortened version; however, it sounds awkward to me despite that. (So, I wouldn't shorten it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about the **maximum number of domains**, you might say

> The maximum number of **domains** is...

If you are asking about the maximum value ***within*** a domain, you might say

> The **domain** limit is...

I think you are asking the second.

Comment: In fact, that is for an SQL database column naming convention: Either domainsLimit or domainLimit ? A customer is limited up to X domains.

Comment: @Nuxwin So, technically, domainsLimit. If you don't mind that it sounds awkward, that's fine. (Since it's a variable name, it doesn't really matter what you call it.)